GraphQL Attach a custom directive to a mutation input variable
I want to be able to apply custom directives to the my mutation input variables. I've tried a variety of solutions, including the example given by graphql-tools, however, I haven't been able to find anything that does the following:
When a mutation request is made, whatever is passed into the input fields should pass their variables into the directive's code to validate that the condition(s) has/have been made before executing what is in the mutation's resolver.
My questions are:

Can custom directives be applied to input fields for directives?
If so, what modifications do I need to make to achieve the desired result in my length directive?

Below is what I have so far. The length directive is the custom directive that I want to use in my mutation and the typedefs.js file is how I have my typedefs currently set up
lengthdirective.js
import { defaultFieldResolver } from "graphql"
import { getDirective, MapperKind, mapSchema } from "@graphql-tools/utils"

function lengthDirective(directiveName) {
    const typeDirectiveArgumentMaps = {}
    
    return {
        lengthDirectiveTypeDefs: `
        
        directive @${directiveName}(
            min: Int,
            max: Int,
            exact: Int
        ) on FIELD_DEFINITION
        `,
        lengthDirectiveTransformer: (schema) =>
            mapSchema(schema, {
                [MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: (fieldConfig) => {
                    const lengthDirective = getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName)?.[0]
                    if (lengthDirective) {
                        const { min, max, exact } = lengthDirective
                        if (requires) {
                            const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = fieldConfig
                            fieldConfig.resolve = async function (source, args, context, info) {
                                const result = await resolve(source, args, context, info)
                                if (typeof result === 'string') {
                                    if ((min !== undefined && result.length < min) || (max !== undefined && result.length > max) || (exact !== undefined && result.length !== exact)) {
                                        let errorMessage = 'The length of the string'
                                        if (min !== undefined) {
                                            errorMessage += ` must be at least ${min} characters`
                                        }
                                        if (min !== undefined && max !== undefined) {
                                            errorMessage != ' and'
                                        }
                                        if (max !== undefined) {
                                            errorMessage += ` must be at most ${max} characters`
                                        }
                                        if (exact !== undefined) {
                                            errorMessage += ` must be exactly ${exact} characters`
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                return result
                            }
                            return fieldConfig
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}

const { lengthDirectiveTypeDefs, lengthDirectiveTransformer } = lengthDirective("length")

export { lengthDirectiveTypeDefs, lengthDirectiveTransformer }


typedefs.js

import { authDirectiveTypeDefs } from "./directives/authDirective.js";
import { lengthDirectiveTypeDefs } from "./directives/lengthDirective.js";

export const TYPE_DEFS = [
  authDirectiveTypeDefs,
  lengthDirectiveTypeDefs,
  `
  type Game {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    platform: [String!]!
    reviews: [Review!]
  }

  type Review @auth(requires: ADMIN) {
    id: ID!
    rating: Int!
    content: String!
    author: Author!
    game: Game!
  }

  type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    verified: Boolean
    reviews: [Review!]
  }

  type Query {
    reviews: [Review]
    review(id: ID!): Review
    games: [Game]
    game(id: ID!): Game
    authors: [Author]
    author(id: ID!): Author
  }

  type Mutation {
    authenticate(name: String! @length(min: 5), password: String!): String
  }
  `
];


